# Ubuntu boots to desktop that looks wrong

Tags: boot

When I boot my laptop I get the login screen. I boot up and it then shows a black screen. Then after waiting a while the Launcher and the panel appears and then my desktop looks this:

[image]

I have also noticed that when booted up it boots up with the command `/dev recovering journal , clearing orphaned mode` rather than the normal command `/dev1 clear`

System:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Intel Core 2 Duo (2.2 GHZ)
Dell Inspiron 1545

Comment: What operating system? What desktop environment? What filesystem on the HDD? Do you see the grub boot options at switch on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems ur desktop is not installed properly... press CTRL + ALT + F1.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity
shutdown -r now
```

Reboot and see if it works !

Comment: This will take some time lo load desktop for first time

Comment: It was working just fine for about now 6 months but now only the prob occured

Comment: Did this command solve ur problem?

Comment: Hi sardapv. Do u know if this command will erase all your data.I also wanted to let you know that its not he first time I booted the Ubuntu, infact I have used it for 5 months now and this is the first time it has happend

Comment: Ya it will just install your desktop back... If any broken..u can keep desktop files somewhere else..m user of Ubuntu from 3 years :) installed several desktop environments..try it :)and let me know..if this doesn't solve then problem is something else

Comment: Thx a lot it WORKED!!

Comment: Most Welcome..:)